# How to gain access to Android GUI having only remote root access to console?

Tags: root-access, remote-control, ssh, remote-access, vnc

I have remote root SSH access to my Android device, i.e. can upload and start programs there.

How to get GUI access, i.e. view the screen and press buttons there remotely.

For X11, `x11vnc` can be used to attach to X session. Are there analogues for Android?

Comment: Something like [VNC servers for Android](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=150#group_671)?

Comment: Yes, that can be installed remotely. Ideally - little tool one-file tool that can be just downloaded and started, like `x11vnc`, but for android.

Comment: Have you checked behind the link? That's exactly what it points to: A listing of VNC servers for Android. Including x11vnc, by the way ;)